# Compare 2 array and highlight difference

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need some help on solving a problem I have. I have a order system, in which each order can have multiply stages. The stages can be changed, deleted and new stages can be made.

When a stage is changed I need to output the new data and the old and put into a mail, and the changes must be highlight. On top of that the stages must be sorted not by id, or stage number but after a date. This Means that a new stage eg. stage 6 can be Placed at the top, if the date is the first upcoming.

My problem is that I can get the comparison right.

Data is from MySQL and after that used in PHP. I have the data in to arrays (old_data, new_data), which looks like this:

Old data:

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3164
        [opr_etape_id] => 307
        [kg] => 35360
        [stålpris] => 369512
        [timer] => 300
        [levuge] => 2
        [etape] => 1
        [ordrenr] => 
        [rev] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3165
        [opr_etape_id] => 308
        [kg] => 18535
        [stålpris] => 193690
        [timer] => 100
        [levuge] => 23
        [etape] => 2
        [ordrenr] => 
        [rev] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3163
        [opr_etape_id] => 3113
        [kg] => 500
        [stålpris] => 5000
        [timer] => 0
        [levuge] => 27
        [etape] => 3
        [ordrenr] => 
        [rev] => 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3162
        [opr_etape_id] => 3122
        [kg] => 40
        [stålpris] => 1000
        [timer] => 0
        [levuge] => 50
        [etape] => 4
        [ordrenr] => 
        [rev] => 
    )
)
```

New data:

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [eId] => 3169
        [id] => 10610
        [opr_etape_id] => 307
        [kg] => 35360
        [stålpris] => 369512
        [timer] => 300
        [levuge] => 2
        [etape] => 1
        [ordrenr] => 49540
        [rev] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [eId] => 3170
        [id] => 10610
        [opr_etape_id] => 308
        [kg] => 18535
        [stålpris] => 193690
        [timer] => 100
        [levuge] => 23
        [etape] => 2
        [ordrenr] => 49540
        [rev] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [eId] => 3168
        [id] => 10610
        [opr_etape_id] => 3113
        [kg] => 500
        [stålpris] => 5000
        [timer] => 0
        [levuge] => 27
        [etape] => 3
        [ordrenr] => 49540
        [rev] => 0
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [eId] => 3166
        [id] => 10610
        [opr_etape_id] => 3166
        [kg] => 1000
        [stålpris] => 50000
        [timer] => 0
        [levuge] => 41
        [etape] => 5
        [ordrenr] => 49540
        [rev] => 0
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [eId] => 3167
        [id] => 10610
        [opr_etape_id] => 3122
        [kg] => 40
        [stålpris] => 1000
        [timer] => 0
        [levuge] => 50
        [etape] => 4
        [ordrenr] => 49540
        [rev] => 0
    )
)
```

How do I compare these, so I can identify the new stage ([etape] => 5) as the new one, and keep the comparison for [etape] => 4

Essentially I need this

New date       Old data

1                 1

2                 2

3                 3

5                                              <= new, highlight this

4                 4

and I need it to be returned in the order the new data has.

Comment: In which technology?

Comment: The arrays seem like output from `var_dump` in `PHP`. Please verify this and add the right tags to the question to help us answer it.

Comment: Still trying to know what output you would like

Comment: Ups, sorry was interrupted at Work, when I posted it, so didn't get it spot on. It's in PHP and the data is coming from MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `array_diff( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $... ] )` ?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't get the difference I wanted. I got 2 different, eventhough only one was changed. But the changed one, was before the last, so I guess array_diff() thinks it is difference - that'll make sense.

My problem is, that I don't just want the differens. I want all from the new array, but I need to highlight the differens. And not differens in array index, but in array values. That is what I can't figure out, and need help to do.

Answer (score 0):

Now I have come up with this.

```
$typer = array("kg", "stålpris", "timer", "levuge");
$nye_nøgler = array_keys($nye_værdier);
$gml_nøgler = array_keys($gml_værdier);

foreach ($nye_nøgler as $ky){
    $besked .= "<tr>";
    $besked .= "<td>Etape ".$nye_værdier[$ky]['etape']."</td>";
    foreach ($gml_nøgler as $gy) {
        for ($k = 0; $k < sizeof($typer); $k++) {
            if (in_array($nye_værdier[$ky][$typer[$k]], $gml_værdier[$gy])){
                $besked .=  "<td align='center'>".number_format($nye_værdier[$ky][$typer[$k]], 0, ',', '.') ."</td>";
            } else {
                $besked .=  "<td align='center'><b><font color='red'>". number_format($nye_værdier[$ky][$typer[$k]], 0, ',', '.') ."</font></b></td>";
            }
        }
    }
    $besked .= "</tr>";
}

$besked .= "</table>";

echo $besked;
```

It's getting there, but this output the data the same times as there are data in $gml_nøgler.
I does this because I need to get hold of the data in $gml_nøgler, so I can check if the data has changed. Is there smarter way to do this, so I would only get the data out once?

Answer (score 0):

Think I have found a solution myself now. Just coundn't see the Wood for the trees.

On the new stages I have a reference to the old stages id. If I use this to pin-point the precise index in the old dataarray, it seems I get the right output. I just need to test it a little more, but the code is as following:

```
$typer = array("kg", "stålpris", "timer", "levuge");
$nye_nøgler = array_keys($nye_værdier);
$gml_nøgler = array_keys($gml_værdier);

foreach ($nye_nøgler as $ky){
    $message .= "<tr>";//<td>".$nye_værdier[$i][ordrenr]." R".$nye_værdier[$i][rev]."</td>";
    $message .= "<td>Etape ".$nye_værdier[$ky]['etape']."</td>";
    for ($k = 0; $k < sizeof($typer); $k++) {
        if ($nye_værdier[$ky][$typer[$k]] == $gml_værdier[$nye_værdier[$ky]['opr_etape_id']][$typer[$k]]) {//Bruger opr_etape_id fra den nye etape til at finde den gamles værdier med
                $message .=  "<td align='center'>".number_format($nye_værdier[$ky][$typer[$k]], 0, ',', '.') ."</td>";
        } else {
                $message .=  "<td align='center'><b><font color='red'>".number_format($nye_værdier[$ky][$typer[$k]], 0, ',', '.')."</font></b></td>";
        }
    }
    $message .= "</tr>";
}
$message .= "</table>";
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm not comfortable with this forum yet. Why didn't is post this last?